# How can I update all columns in table?

Tags: php, postgresql, codeigniter

I have two tables A and

```
update A set (*) = (select  * from B where id = 1) where session_id ='123';
```

Both tables have save column EXCEPT for the session_id on table A. Any idea on how I can update the record without declaring all the columns?

The output should like be the result of the following query but I should use this:

```
insert into A select * from B;
update A set session_id ='a';
```

I want to know how to insert the session_id FIRST then ALL records.

Comment: Have a read of codeigniter active database records http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html#update

Comment: on the docu, you still need to declare fields. Does it mean there's no way to implement my inquiry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with codeigniter specifics, but if all columns in table B are declared in the same order in table A and then followed by `session_id`, then you can do:

```
INSERT INTO "A"
  SELECT *, '123'
  FROM "B"
  WHERE id = 1;
```

If `session_id` comes first in table A, followed by all columns of table B in declared order, then you simple swap the column order on the `SELECT` statement. If the order is not identical (apart from `session_id`) you are out of luck.